# Dart with jQuery reference running Dartium throws unhandled exception

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, dart

when running in dartium i'll get exception:

> Source not available for CALL_NO_FUNCTION_AS_CONSTRUCTOR()
>
> Breaking on exception: TypeError: undefined is not a function
>
> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function   inlineSVG
>   (//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.1/jquery.mobile-1.4.1.js:1967:9)
>   (//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.1/jquery.mobile-1.4.1.js:14886:13) 
>   fire (//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js:3048:30)   self.fireWith
>   (//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js:3160:7)   jQuery.extend.ready
>   (//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js:433:13)   completed
>   (//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js:104:11) event.returnValue is
>   deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.

Note. took out "http:" from the "//code.jquery.com/" due to lack of my stackoverflow account

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Sample app</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/web.css">

    <!-- import the polymer elements -->

    <link rel="import" href="clickcounter.html">
    <!--
    <link rel="import" href="Components/testElement.html">
    -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.1/jquery.mobile-1.4.1.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/jqm-demos.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div data-role="page" class="jqm-demos jqm-home">
      <div data-role="header" class="jqm-header">
        <a href="#nav-panel" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext" class="jqm-navmenu-link">Menu</a>
        <a href="#add-form" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="notext" class="jqm-navmenu-gear">Add</a>
        <h1>Header here</h1>
      </div>
      <div data-role="main" class="ui-content jqm-content">
        <h1>Main Content</h1>
      </div>
      <div data-role="panel" id="nav-panel" data-position="left" data-display="overlay" data-theme="a" class="jqm-navmenu-panel">
        <ul data-role="listview" class="jqm-list">
            <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Accordion</a></li>
            <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">AJAX Navigation</a></li>
            <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Autocomplete</a></li>
            <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Buttons</a></li>
            <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Checkboxes</a></li>
            <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Collapsibles</a></li>
            <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Controlgroup</a></li>
            <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Dialogs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Fixed toolbars</a></li>
            <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Flip switch toggle</a></li>
            <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Footer toolbar</a></li>
            <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Form elements</a></li>
            <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Grids</a></li>
            <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Header toolbar</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
      <div data-role="panel" data-position="right" data-position-fixed="true" data-display="overlay" data-theme="a" id="add-form">
        <form class="userform">
          <h2>Login</h2>
          <label for="name">Username:</label>
          <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" data-clear-btn="true" data-mini="true">
          <label for="password">Password:</label>
          <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" data-clear-btn="true" autocomplete="off" data-mini="true">
          <div class="ui-grid-a">
            <div class="ui-block-a"><a href="#" data-rel="close" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-b ui-mini">Cancel</a></div>
            <div class="ui-block-b"><a href="#" data-rel="close" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-a ui-mini">Save</a></div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" class="jqm-footer">
        <h1>Footer</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.1/jquery.mobile-1.4.1.js"></script>
    <script type="application/dart" src="web.dart"></script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
    <script src="packages/browser/interop.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

any suggestions would be great.

Comment: problem solved with release of Dart SDK version 1.2.0-dev.5.7